# OpenGL ES 2.0 GLSL Barrel Distortion Shader not working

Tags: opengl-es, glsl, shader, distortion

i took the code from the OpenGL ES 2.0 Tutorial from  : github.com/learnopengles/Learn-OpenGLES-Tutorials

and customized the class "LessonOneRenderer" to test a barrel distortin Shader like mentioned on this site:

www.geeks3d.com/20140213/glsl-shader-library-fish-eye-and-dome-and-barrel-distortion-post-processing-filters/2/

This is the "untouched" Result without calling the distort() function:

http://fs1.directupload.net/images/150125/hw746rcn.png

and the result calling the function :

http://fs2.directupload.net/images/150125/f84arxoj.png

```
/**
 * This class implements our custom renderer. Note that the GL10 parameter passed in is unused for OpenGL ES 2.0
 * renderers -- the static class GLES20 is used instead.
 */
public class LessonOneRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer 
{
    /**
     * Store the model matrix. This matrix is used to move models from object space (where each model can be thought
     * of being located at the center of the universe) to world space.
     */
    private float[] mModelMatrix = new float[16];

    /**
     * Store the view matrix. This can be thought of as our camera. This matrix transforms world space to eye space;
     * it positions things relative to our eye.
     */
    private float[] mViewMatrix = new float[16];

    /** Store the projection matrix. This is used to project the scene onto a 2D viewport. */
    private float[] mProjectionMatrix = new float[16];

    /** Allocate storage for the final combined matrix. This will be passed into the shader program. */
    private float[] mMVPMatrix = new float[16];

    /** Store our model data in a float buffer. */
    private final FloatBuffer mTriangle1Vertices;


    /** This will be used to pass in the transformation matrix. */
    private int mMVPMatrixHandle;

    /** This will be used to pass in model position information. */
    private int mPositionHandle;

    /** This will be used to pass in model color information. */
    private int mColorHandle;

    /** How many bytes per float. */
    private final int mBytesPerFloat = 4;

    /** How many elements per vertex. */
    private final int mStrideBytes = 7 * mBytesPerFloat;    

    /** Offset of the position data. */
    private final int mPositionOffset = 0;

    /** Size of the position data in elements. */
    private final int mPositionDataSize = 3;

    /** Offset of the color data. */
    private final int mColorOffset = 3;

    /** Size of the color data in elements. */
    private final int mColorDataSize = 4;       





    private FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;
    private ShortBuffer drawListBuffer;

    // number of coordinates per vertex in this array
    static final int COORDS_PER_VERTEX = 3;
                                //   X      Y     Z 
    static float squareCoords[] = { -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,   // top left
                                    -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,   // bottom left
                                     0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,   // bottom right
                                     0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f }; // top right

    private short drawOrder[] = { 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3 }; // order to draw vertices
    float color[] = { 0.63671875f, 0.76953125f, 0.22265625f, 1.0f };


    static final int vertexStride = COORDS_PER_VERTEX * 4;
    static final int vertexCount = 4;
    private ByteBuffer dlb;

    /**
     * Initialize the model data.
     */
    public LessonOneRenderer()
    {   


         ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(squareCoords.length * 4); // (# of coordinate values * 4 bytes per float)
            bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
            vertexBuffer = bb.asFloatBuffer();
            vertexBuffer.put(squareCoords);
            vertexBuffer.position(0);

            // initialize byte buffer for the draw list
            ByteBuffer dlb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(drawOrder.length * 2); // (# of coordinate values * 2 bytes per short)
            dlb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
            drawListBuffer = dlb.asShortBuffer();
            drawListBuffer.put(drawOrder);
            drawListBuffer.position(0);



        // Define points for equilateral triangles.

        // This triangle is red, green, and blue.
        final float[] triangle1VerticesData = {
                // X, Y, Z, 
                // R, G, B, A
                -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,  // top left
                1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,

                -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,// bottom left
                0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,

                0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, // bottom right
                0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f
                ,
                0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f, // top right
                0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f

        };


        // Initialize the buffers.
        mTriangle1Vertices = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(triangle1VerticesData.length * mBytesPerFloat)
        .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();    
        mTriangle1Vertices.put(triangle1VerticesData).position(0);

          // initialize byte buffer for the draw list
        dlb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(drawOrder.length * 2); // (# of coordinate values * 2 bytes per short)
        dlb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        drawListBuffer = dlb.asShortBuffer();
        drawListBuffer.put(drawOrder);
        drawListBuffer.position(0);


    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 glUnused, EGLConfig config) 
    {
        // Set the background clear color to gray.
        GLES20.glClearColor(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);

        // Position the eye behind the origin.
        final float eyeX = 0.0f;
        final float eyeY = 0.0f;
        final float eyeZ = 1.5f;

        // We are looking toward the distance
        final float lookX = 0.0f;
        final float lookY = 0.0f;
        final float lookZ = -5.0f;

        // Set our up vector. This is where our head would be pointing were we holding the camera.
        final float upX = 0.0f;
        final float upY = 1.0f;
        final float upZ = 0.0f;

        // Set the view matrix. This matrix can be said to represent the camera position.
        // NOTE: In OpenGL 1, a ModelView matrix is used, which is a combination of a model and
        // view matrix. In OpenGL 2, we can keep track of these matrices separately if we choose.
        Matrix.setLookAtM(mViewMatrix, 0, eyeX, eyeY, eyeZ, lookX, lookY, lookZ, upX, upY, upZ);




        final String vertexShader =
            "uniform mat4 u_MVPMatrix;      \n"     // A constant representing the combined model/view/projection matrix.

          + "attribute vec4 a_Position;     \n"     // Per-vertex position information we will pass in.
          + "attribute vec4 a_Color;        \n"     // Per-vertex color information we will pass in.              
          + "varying vec4 a_Pos;            \n"
          + "varying vec4 v_Color;          \n"     // This will be passed into the fragment shader.
          +" "
          +"vec4 Distort(vec4 p){                   \n"
          +"    float BarrelPower = 0.4;            \n"
          +"    vec2 v = p.xy / p.w;                \n"
          +"    float radius = length(v);           \n"
          +"    if (radius > 0.0){                  \n"
          +"        float theta = atan(v.y,v.x);    \n"
          +"        radius = pow(radius, BarrelPower);\n"
          +"        v.x = radius * cos(theta);      \n"
          +"        v.y = radius * sin(theta);      \n"
          +"        p.xy = v.xy * p.w;              \n"
          +" }"
          +"                                        \n"
          +" return p;                              \n"
          +" }                                      \n"
          + "void main()                    \n"     // The entry point for our vertex shader.
          + "{                              \n"
          + "   v_Color = a_Color;          \n"     // Pass the color through to the fragment shader. 
          + "   vec4 P = u_MVPMatrix * a_Position;"                             // It will be interpolated across the triangle.
          + "   gl_Position = Distort(P);   \n"     // gl_Position is a special variable used to store the final position.
          + "                  \n"     // Multiply the vertex by the matrix to get the final point in                                                                    
          + "}                              \n";    // normalized screen coordinates.

        final String fragmentShader =
                    // Set the default precision to medium. We don't need as high of a 
           "varying vec4 a_Pos;"                                // precision in the fragment shader.                
          + "varying vec4 v_Color;          \n"     // This is the color from the vertex shader interpolated across the 
                                                    // triangle per fragment.             
          + "void main()                    \n"     // The entry point for our fragment shader.
          + "{   vec4 c = vec4(1.0);                           \n"
          + "   gl_FragColor = v_Color;    \n"      // Pass the color directly through the pipeline.          
          + "}                              \n";                                                

        // Load in the vertex shader.
        int vertexShaderHandle = GLES20.glCreateShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER);

        if (vertexShaderHandle != 0) 
        {
            // Pass in the shader source.
            GLES20.glShaderSource(vertexShaderHandle, vertexShader);

            // Compile the shader.
            GLES20.glCompileShader(vertexShaderHandle);

            // Get the compilation status.
            final int[] compileStatus = new int[1];
            GLES20.glGetShaderiv(vertexShaderHandle, GLES20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS, compileStatus, 0);

            // If the compilation failed, delete the shader.
            if (compileStatus[0] == 0) 
            {               
                GLES20.glDeleteShader(vertexShaderHandle);
                vertexShaderHandle = 0;
            }
        }

        if (vertexShaderHandle == 0)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error creating vertex shader.");
        }

        // Load in the fragment shader shader.
        int fragmentShaderHandle = GLES20.glCreateShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

        if (fragmentShaderHandle != 0) 
        {
            // Pass in the shader source.
            GLES20.glShaderSource(fragmentShaderHandle, fragmentShader);

            // Compile the shader.
            GLES20.glCompileShader(fragmentShaderHandle);

            // Get the compilation status.
            final int[] compileStatus = new int[1];
            GLES20.glGetShaderiv(fragmentShaderHandle, GLES20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS, compileStatus, 0);

            // If the compilation failed, delete the shader.
            if (compileStatus[0] == 0) 
            {               
                GLES20.glDeleteShader(fragmentShaderHandle);
                fragmentShaderHandle = 0;
            }
        }

        if (fragmentShaderHandle == 0)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error creating fragment shader.");
        }

        // Create a program object and store the handle to it.
        int programHandle = GLES20.glCreateProgram();

        if (programHandle != 0) 
        {
            // Bind the vertex shader to the program.
            GLES20.glAttachShader(programHandle, vertexShaderHandle);           

            // Bind the fragment shader to the program.
            GLES20.glAttachShader(programHandle, fragmentShaderHandle);

            // Bind attributes
            GLES20.glBindAttribLocation(programHandle, 0, "a_Position");
            GLES20.glBindAttribLocation(programHandle, 1, "a_Color");

            // Link the two shaders together into a program.
            GLES20.glLinkProgram(programHandle);

            // Get the link status.
            final int[] linkStatus = new int[1];
            GLES20.glGetProgramiv(programHandle, GLES20.GL_LINK_STATUS, linkStatus, 0);

            // If the link failed, delete the program.
            if (linkStatus[0] == 0) 
            {               
                GLES20.glDeleteProgram(programHandle);
                programHandle = 0;
            }
        }

        if (programHandle == 0)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error creating program.");
        }

        // Set program handles. These will later be used to pass in values to the program.
        mMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(programHandle, "u_MVPMatrix");        
        mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(programHandle, "a_Position");
        mColorHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(programHandle, "a_Color");        

        // Tell OpenGL to use this program when rendering.
        GLES20.glUseProgram(programHandle);        
    }   

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 glUnused, int width, int height) 
    {
        // Set the OpenGL viewport to the same size as the surface.
        GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

        // Create a new perspective projection matrix. The height will stay the same
        // while the width will vary as per aspect ratio.
        final float ratio = (float) width / height;
        final float left = -ratio;
        final float right = ratio;
        final float bottom = -1.0f;
        final float top = 1.0f;
        final float near = 1.0f;
        final float far = 10.0f;

        Matrix.frustumM(mProjectionMatrix, 0, left, right, bottom, top, near, far);
    }   

    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 glUnused) 
    {
        GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);                    

        // Do a complete rotation every 10 seconds.
        long time = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() % 10000L;
        float angleInDegrees = (360.0f / 10000.0f) * ((int) time);

        // Draw the triangle facing straight on.
        //Matrix.setIdentityM(mModelMatrix, 0);
        //Matrix.rotateM(mModelMatrix, 0, angleInDegrees, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);        
        //drawTriangle(mTriangle1Vertices);


        //Draw Square
        Matrix.setIdentityM(mModelMatrix, 0);
        Matrix.translateM(mModelMatrix, 0, 0.0f, -0.7f, 0.0f);

        //Matrix.rotateM(mModelMatrix, 0, angleInDegrees, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);        
        this.drawSquare(mTriangle1Vertices);


        //Draw Square
        Matrix.setIdentityM(mModelMatrix, 0);
        Matrix.translateM(mModelMatrix, 0, 0.0f, 0.7f, 0.0f);

        //Matrix.rotateM(mModelMatrix, 0, angleInDegrees, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);        
        this.drawSquare(mTriangle1Vertices);


        // Draw one translated a bit down and rotated to be flat on the ground.
        //Matrix.setIdentityM(mModelMatrix, 0);
        //Matrix.translateM(mModelMatrix, 0, 0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
        //Matrix.rotateM(mModelMatrix, 0, 90.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        //Matrix.rotateM(mModelMatrix, 0, angleInDegrees, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);        
        //drawTriangle(mTriangle2Vertices);

        // Draw one translated a bit to the right and rotated to be facing to the left.
        //Matrix.setIdentityM(mModelMatrix, 0);
        //Matrix.translateM(mModelMatrix, 0, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        //Matrix.rotateM(mModelMatrix, 0, 90.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        //Matrix.rotateM(mModelMatrix, 0, angleInDegrees, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        //drawTriangle(mTriangle3Vertices);


//        test.draw();
    }   

    /**
     * Draws a triangle from the given vertex data.
     * 
     * @param aTriangleBuffer The buffer containing the vertex data.
     */
    private void drawTriangle(final FloatBuffer aTriangleBuffer)
    {       
        // Pass in the position information
        aTriangleBuffer.position(mPositionOffset);
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, mPositionDataSize, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
                mStrideBytes, aTriangleBuffer);        

        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);        

        // Pass in the color information
        aTriangleBuffer.position(mColorOffset);
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mColorHandle, mColorDataSize, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
                mStrideBytes, aTriangleBuffer);        

        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mColorHandle);

        // This multiplies the view matrix by the model matrix, and stores the result in the MVP matrix
        // (which currently contains model * view).
        Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mViewMatrix, 0, mModelMatrix, 0);

        // This multiplies the modelview matrix by the projection matrix, and stores the result in the MVP matrix
        // (which now contains model * view * projection).
        Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjectionMatrix, 0, mMVPMatrix, 0);

        GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mMVPMatrix, 0);
        GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);                               
    }

    private void drawSquare(final FloatBuffer aTriangleBuffer)
    {       
        // Pass in the position information
        aTriangleBuffer.position(mPositionOffset);
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, mPositionDataSize, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
                mStrideBytes, aTriangleBuffer);        

        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);        

        // Pass in the color information
        aTriangleBuffer.position(mColorOffset);
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mColorHandle, COORDS_PER_VERTEX, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
                vertexStride, aTriangleBuffer);        

        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mColorHandle);

        // This multiplies the view matrix by the model matrix, and stores the result in the MVP matrix
        // (which currently contains model * view).
        Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mViewMatrix, 0, mModelMatrix, 0);

        // This multiplies the modelview matrix by the projection matrix, and stores the result in the MVP matrix
        // (which now contains model * view * projection).
        Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjectionMatrix, 0, mMVPMatrix, 0);

        GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mMVPMatrix, 0);
        GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 4);                               
    }


}
```

Does anybody have an idea what i'm missing to distort the squares like in the example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You apply the distortion effect in the vertex shader. So all you are doing is moving the 4 corners of those spheres. You can't achieve the desired effect that way.

Threre are different options. You theoretically could use some higher tesselation for your squares, so you just create a 2D grid of vertices, which then can indivudually be moved according to the distortion. If your grid is fine enough, the piecewise-linear nature of that approximation will not be visible anymore.

However, such effects are typically done differently. One usually does not tune the geometric models for specific effects. That kind of distortions usually are applied in screen-space, as a *post-processing* effect (and the link you posted does exactly this). The idea is that you can render the whole scene into a texture, and draw a single tetxured rectangle filling the whole screen as the final pass. In that pass, you can apply the distortion to the texture coordinates in the fragment shader, just as in the original example.

All of that can be done in OpenGL ES, too. The keywords to look for are RTT (render to texture) and FBOs (framebuffer objects). On GLES, this feature is available as the [`OES_framebuffer_object`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/OES/OES_framebuffer_object.txt) extension (which is widely supported on most ES implementations).

However, using that stuff is definitively a bit more advanced than your typical "lessson 1" of some tutorial, you might want to read some other lessons first before trying that... ;)

Comment: FBOs are standard in ES 2.0. And I certainly hope that nobody uses ES 1.x anymore. ES 1.x wouldn't be an option in this case anyway, since it doesn't support shaders.

Comment: Managed it by rendering it to an texture like in this example : http://maninara.blogspot.ca/2012/09/render-camera-preview-using-opengl-es.html

Comment: After extending the example i got a new issue : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28250867/opengl-es-2-0-shader-on-texture-not-working